# jQuery DrawSVG: Call a function when draw-on-scroll is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, callback

I'm using [jQuery DrawSVG](http://leocs.me/jquery-drawsvg/) by Leonardo Santos to draw a simple `SVG path` on a page, as the page is being scrolled.

I'd like to be able to call a function once the path is fully drawn.

This is the script for drawing the path on scroll:

```
var $doc = $(document),
  $win = $(window),
  $svg = $("#Layer_1").drawsvg({
    stagger: 0
  }),
  max = $doc.height() - $win.height();

$win.on("scroll", function() {
  var p = $win.scrollTop() / max;
  $svg.drawsvg("progress", p);
});
```

DrawSVG provides a built-in option to fire a callback once an animated drawing of a path is finished:

```
var $svg = $("svg").drawsvg({
  callback: function() {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Can I do the same/something similar for drawing on scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
$win.on("scroll", function() {
  var p = $win.scrollTop() / max;
  $svg.drawsvg("progress", p);
  if (p >= 1)
    myCallbackFunction();
});
```

Comment: I got a follow up question about configuring this draw-on-scroll setup even more. Maybe you got some advice here as well? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121210/jquery-drawsvg-draw-path-as-far-as-scroll-bar-position-scrolltop